# How to prove that $x^n-x^{n-1}-....-x-1=0$ has one real root when $n$ is odd and two real roots when $n$ is even

Tags: polynomials, roots, fibonacci-numbers

Let $NF(n)$ denote the $n$-bonacci number such that $$NF(n)^n-NF(n)^{n-1}-...-NF(n)-1=0$$ Prove that if $2|n$ then there are two real solutions to the above equation, else there is one real solution. I was able to prove that the $n$-bonacci numbers are solutions to $NF(n)^{n+1}-2NF(n)^n+1=0$ which simplifies the polynomial. But I don't know how to approach my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Rewrite it $x^n−\frac{x^n−1}{x−1}$ and study the numerator $x^{n+1}−2x^n+1$

The sign of its derivative should be easy to find as this factors well.

Show it has $2$ or $3$ roots, but the trivial root $x=1$ is spurious for the original problem.

Comment: Actually may you please write the whole solution? I thought I could go on but I couldn't.